# a:visited cancels hover actions in a table

Tags: css

All my scripts and code are at http://asteenburg.magix.net
It's just a site for me to mess around with and learn CSS, JS, and Jquery.

Information around the problem:
I have a menu link/button and a navigation table both on a JQuery fadeIn script. Both elements also have a hover class. When a user hovers over the menu link/button it works as programmed. When a user hovers over the navigation table in the menu, the links disappear.

Problem:
I've discovered the a:visited class prevents the hover state from working in the navigation table. I know it is probably something with specificity (which I'm also trying to learn), but I have changed my CSS around different combinations but I have run out of ideas and can't find anything in Stackoverflow, Google, etc. There were a couple suggestions from other similar posts but couldn't really get it to work for me.

Please, don't close this question because I'm dying to know what's causing this. Many thanks.

UPDATE: If anyone knows of any valuable CSS resources, I would be interested to check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting all of your links up accordingly and then you will not experience any conflicts

```
a:link {
    color: green;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: green;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: red;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: I have them in the said order. When I set just the table up with the links in the proper order, with no other CSS other than the table classes, it works fine. That's why I think there is something in my CSS causing it but I just can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a complete answer, and I'll have to play around with it some more. BUT, I changed my CSS from this:

.PanelTable { border: none; }
.PanelTable td { border: none; font-family: "Gotham Book"; padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px; }
.Menu td:hover { background-color: #FFF; opacity: 0.3; color: #B8B8B8; }

To THIS:

.PanelTable td { border: none; padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px; }
.PanelTable td:hover { background-color: #000; opacity: 0.3; color: #B8B8B8; font-family: "Gotham Book"; }

Only problem I have now is my hover background cannot be #FFF....Works fine with #000.
I'll play around with it some more. We shall see.

Comment: Further to my answer, I've changed the CSS to the following: .panelTable td { padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px; }
.PanelTable td:hover { background-color: #CCC; opacity: 0.3; color: #000; font-family: "Gotham Book"; } Then added background-color: #5A5A5A; opacity: 0.5; for styling. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember this: the link styles MUST be in this order to work properly.

1. a:link - a normal, unvisited link
2. a:visited - a link the user has visited
3. a:hover - a link when the user mouses over it
4. a:active - a link the moment it is clicked

To learn more about styling links (and anything HTML, CSS, or JS for that matter) go to [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp).